# MySQL query conditional or subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm finding that SQL related questions are very difficult to express conversationally so please forgive me if this makes no sense.

I'm migrating data out of a CMS database to MySQL and I would like to simplify the data structure wherever possible. The current category scheme has **7 categories** and has an item to category relationship setup as a many-to-many so a junction table is required.

It would be better setup as two one-to-many relationships so that an extra table is not required. The actual category setup that I need is as follows:

**Category 1**

```
Option 1
Option 2
```

**Category 2**

```
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5
Option 6
Option 7
```

Each item belongs to one value for `Category 1`, and one value for `Category 2`. This is the general form of the query I'm creating:

```
SELECT items.entry_id, categories.cat_id
FROM items
INNER JOIN categories
ON items.entry_id = categories.entry_id
WHERE items.item_type = 6
```

How would I add a conditional or sub query so that I got the results of the `SELECT` clause like:

```
SELECT items.entry_id, categories.cat_id1, categories.cat_id2
```

where the value of `cat_id1` and `cat_id2` are the values described above?

****Update****
I have made some progress getting the query I need (the tables are too complicated to post here for examples but here is a sample query):

```
SELECT exp_weblog_data.entry_id, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_27 AS Title, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_29, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_32, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_33, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_28, 
exp_weblog_data.field_id_84, 
exp_relationships.rel_child_id, 
CASE WHEN exp_category_posts.cat_id = '15' OR exp_category_posts.cat_id = '16' THEN exp_category_posts.cat_id END as cat1,
CASE WHEN exp_category_posts.cat_id = '17' OR exp_category_posts.cat_id = '20' THEN exp_category_posts.cat_id END as cat2
FROM exp_weblog_data
INNER JOIN exp_relationships
ON exp_weblog_data.entry_id = exp_relationships.rel_parent_id
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts
ON exp_weblog_data.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id
WHERE exp_weblog_data.weblog_id = 6
```

This gets me the two columns I want for Cat1 and Cat 2 but there are still two problems here - the inner join on exp_category_posts is resulting in 2 rows for each record where I only want one row for each value of entry_id. Secondly, in the case statements, I want to set a value of A if cat_id = 15 and B if cat_id = 16 but I can't seem to find the right syntax for this without getting errors.

I hope this clears things up a bit!

Comment: maybe you can take a picture of you tables, is hard undestand you only with words

Comment: Sample data and desired results are a great way of explaining things.

Comment: I agree but this CMS database is a huge mess and its difficult to use a real example when I have 100 columns but only need 6 or seven of them. I'll try to figure out how to clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonable way to avoid an extra table when setting up a many-to-many relationship.

Do *not* have multiple columns for multiple categories (`cat_id1`, `cat_id2`, ...).

Do *not* put multiple ids in a single column ("123,234,345").

Both of those lead to problems that are worse than having the mapping table.

Comment: The many-to-many relationship was setup by the cookie-cutter CMS database structure and is not necessary. I'm trying to get at the appropriate query to get the categories back into a single table.